# MFC, CMap class iterator

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm mapping some keys and their values and I want to know how to use the MFC class CMap iterator I want to make some keys and values then type the key or value  and if I typed the value all the keys with the same value get shown.

Comment: My advice is: don't use `CMap` but use `std::map` instead.

Comment: The only reason you'd ever want to use a `CMap` is if you need built-in serialization and/or `CRuntimeClass` services. That's rare. Use a C++ standard container instead.

Comment: In legacy projects you don't always have such a luxury as refactoring by replacing CMap with std::map, this is why such question might be arisen (everyone already forgotten how to iterate them)

Answer (score 3):

In order to iterate over `CMap` do the following:

```
    POSITION pos = dataCollection.GetStartPosition();
    while(pos)
    {
        dataCollection.GetNextAssoc(pos, key, value);

        // TODO: do something here
    }
```

But I would suggest switching to standard `std::map`.